# Secure a java embedded web service with javax.jws without application server

Tags: java, service, web

I wrote the following code to implement a Java web service that communicates with an application written in another language on the same host:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService(name = "MyWebService") 
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED) 
public class MyWebService { 

    @WebMethod(operationName = "methodName", action = "urn:#methodName") 
    @WebResult(name = "result",  partName = "output") 
    public String methodName(@WebParam(name = "param1",  partName = "input")  String param1,
                                        @WebParam(name = "param2",  partName = "input")  String param2){

            // ...do something

        return "You called this service with params: "  + param1 + "," + param2;
    }
```

Since requirements are not to use an application server to expose the web service I instantiated the service from another class as follows:

```
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new MyWebService());
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7777/MyWebService");
        endpoint.publish(url.toString());
```

Questions:

1) Which is the simplest way to secure this service with username and password considering the architecture of this project?
Any code sample would be greatly appreciated.

2) I made some research and found the use of SOAPHandler and I think it would work for me.
In the case of using the SOAPHandler class how do I add headers to the message to require authentication from the client?

Thank you in advance

---

thanks so much for the response that's the direction I'm following too but

when I check any of the headers for example:

```
SOAPHeader header = soapContext.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();
Iterator<SOAPElement> iterator = header.getAllAttributes();
```

I get a nullpointer exception...any ideas?

Comment: If this is really running on localhost, I'd (hardcode) the server to only accept connections from localhost and/or configure the network to not allow the rest of the world to talk to this port.

Comment: I can't do that because the architecture is not up to me and the two applications might be relocated one day in the quickest way possible

Answer (score 0):

I did a working program. Just to add to what you already found out, following is a way to use handler

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new MyWebService());
        Binding binding = endpoint.getBinding();
        List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>(1);
        handlerChain.add(new MyHandler());
        binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7777/MyWebService");
        endpoint.publish(url.toString());
```

`MyHandler` is class extending `Handler` interface.  Alternately, you can use `@HandlerChain` annotation which will need an xml configuration file for handlers. Configure this for **incoming messages** only

```
public class MyHandler implements SOAPHandler{

    @Override
    public Set<?> getHeaders() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(MessageContext context) {
        System.out.println("Hehehe the handler");

        SOAPMessageContext soapContext = (SOAPMessageContext)context;
        try {
            SOAPHeader header = soapContext.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();
            //Check there if the required data (username/password) is present in header or not and return true/false accordingly. 
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

From the client side also, if your client is using JAB-WS, you will have to use client handlers. Following is a typical JAX-WS client invocation example

```
Dispatch<Source> dispatch = … create a Dispatch<Source>
dispatch.getBinding().setHandlerChain(chain)
Source request = … create a Source object
Source response = dispatch.invoke(request);
```

Here the handler in chain will add header to outgoing request. Configure this for **Outgoing** messages only.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is fair enough.
Concerning the authentication you can just expose a method for passing user name and password as login credentials.
Once the user has provided the correct credentials the user has been authenticated.
**Note:** Now you **must** maintain session data and make sure that an incoming request is from an authenticated user. The `Endpoint` just deploys internally a lightweight http server. You must design you web service implementation to keep "state" among requests.

You have 2 more options.

1. Do the authentication at the SOAP level. I would not really recomend
   it. But if you do, note that the `Endpoint` does not deploy a
   `WSDL`.  So you must communicate exactly to the client connecting,
   the `SOAP` header you expect. It is possible though to write a `WSDL` by
   yourself and "attach" it to the `Endpoint`.
2. Do the authentication at the http request level. I.e. add a token or
   cookie to the http request. To be honest I do not remember if this
   is easy using the `Endpoint`